# problem with PHP preg_match function

Tags: php

I am trying to get all images path from a simple HTML code using preg_match function but I did not get it right. here is my code:

```
$meta='<img src=\"imgdir/4fd60181316c0cb257628528adb1c342.gif\"><br><img src=\"imgdir/e2326f439cc5f8c201b411bd66eaf9a0.gif\"><br>';
$pattern = "/^imgdir\/[a-zA-Z0-9].*(png|jpg|gif)/i";
preg_match($pattern, $meta, $result);

print_r($result);
```

please help me to get all images path. example: `imgdir/4fd60181316c0cb257628528adb1c342.gif`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex has a few issues:

1. You should not anchor at the beginning of the string (remove the `^`)
2. The `*` quantifier should be put after the group `[]`
3. The `.` should be properly escaped so that it matches a literal period
4. This last one is not an error, but since you are using the case-insensitive modifier `/i` there's no need to specify both `a-z` and `A-Z`

The correct is:

```
$meta='<img src=\"imgdir/4fd60181316c0cb257628528adb1c342.gif\"><br><img src=\"imgdir/e2326f439cc5f8c201b411bd66eaf9a0.gif\"><br>';
$pattern = "/imgdir\\/[a-z0-9]*\\.(png|jpg|gif)/i";
preg_match($pattern, $meta, $result);

print_r($result);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/txd46)**.

Answer (score 1):

^ means the beginning of the string so that wont work , try this:

```
$pattern = "/imgdir\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.(png|jpg|gif)/i";
```

Comment: You'll want to escape the . `\\.` so that it only matches a literal period. You'll also need to escape the backslashes since you are using double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "/^imgdir\/[a-zA-Z0-9].*(png|jpg|gif)/i";
```

This will match only one alpha-numeric character since you have the . and the * transposed. Try swapping them. You may also have to escape the dot, I'm not sure about that.